# .Net core 3.1 After publish Antiforgery.dll was not found

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, antiforgerytoken, razorlight

I have a simple application with a ContactUs form built using .Net core 3.1. I am using Razor light package for rendering the razor template and using Fluent email api.

During development, everything works fine. But as soon as I publish the app I received the following error when I try to send an email

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Reference

   at BondhEShams.Web.Controllers.HomeController.ContactUs(Contact model) in E:\Work\AbdulMalikYoosufani\BondhEShams\BondhEShams\BondhEShams.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 85

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

How to resolve this issue? I even add the following line in my project file

```
<PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
```

But that also didn't work out. The error only occurred after publish. I also notice there is no Antiforgery.dll in the publish a directory

Comment: According to this github [issue](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/294), you could try to add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation nuget package in your application.

Comment: that's already installed

Comment: Did you end up solving this ?